# How to stop getting data in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app using Firestore as my backend. I need to get every new change from database.

**Code**

```
EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> listener = new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            DataClass dataClass = snapshot.toObject(DataClass.class);
            processesData(dataClass); // process data from db.
        }
    }
};

ListenerRegistration listenerReg = dataDocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(listener);
```

When I close the application, the app is still getting the data.

I read that I can close the connection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve this, you need to stop listening for changes and this can be done in your `onStop()` method by calling `remove()` method on your `ListenerRegistration` object like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (listenerReg != null) {
        listenerReg.remove();
    }
}
```

Remember, when you are using [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) you attach a listener that gets called for every change that takes place in your database. So this is happening also when your app is closed so it's mandatory to [detach the listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before the activity gets destroyed.

If in your app you don't need to get the data in real-time, you can the use a [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) call directly on the reference, which just reads the document only once. Since it only reads once, there is no listener to be removed. This is the correspondent of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` used in the Firebase Realtime database.

As also @giudigior said in his answer, you can also pass your activity as the first argument in the `addSnapshotListener()` method, so Firestore can clean up the listeners automatically when the activity is stopped.

```
ListenerRegistration listenerReg = dataDocumentReference
            .addSnapshotListener(YourActivity.this, listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the activity in the `addSnapshotListener`, so `Firestore` can clean up the listeners automatically when the activity is stopped.

```
ListenerRegistration listenerReg = dataDocumentReference.addSnapshotListener(MainActivity.this, listener);
```

I've added `MainActivity` just as an example. You have to add your `Activity` to make it work.